# Is it possible to set the value of `this` when using Sinon.JS and Rewire?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

**Background**

If I have the following module:

```
this_module: {

    foo: {};

    set_this_foo: function () {

        this.foo.boo = 'something';
        return this.foo;
    }
}
```

and use [Rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire) to import the private function and then unit test this function using [Sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org):

```
var set_this_foo = app.__get__('this_module.set_this_foo');
var spy = sinon.spy(set_this_foo);

spy();

expect(spy).to.have.returned({boo: 'something'});
```

I get the error message:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'boo' of undefined

because `this` ends up having the value of the global object. I can fix this issue by defining a global variable named `foo` before running the test, but would prefer not to pollute the global namespace.

**Question**

Is there an (elegant) way to define the value of `this` in relation to `spy()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this a bit differently:

```
var myModule = app.__get__('this_module');
var spy      = sinon.spy(myModule, 'set_this_foo');

myModule.set_this_foo();

expect(spy).to.have.returned({ boo : 'something' });
```

Since you can also refer to the spy by using the original method name (besides just `spy`), calling that will make sure that it's called in the correct context.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much.